# npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy

Tags: angular, npm, package, devops, gitlab-ci

I have an Angular Gitlab repo. After the last gitlab-ci update, my packaging job fails and throws this error :

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/[id]/packages/npm/[repo_name]
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
```

this is my packaging script :

```
# Package
.package_gitlab: &package_gitlab
  stage: publish
  image: node:12-alpine3.10
  script:
    - npm --version
    - sed -i -e "s/VERSION-CI/$VERSION/g" ./deploy/delete-package.js
    - node ./deploy/delete-package.js
    - sed -i -e "s/VERSION-CI/$VERSION/g" ./deploy/package.json
    - sed -i -e "s/PROJECT-ID-CI/$CI_PROJECT_ID/g" ./deploy/package.json
    - sed -i -e "s/PROJECT-ID-CI/$CI_PROJECT_ID/g" ./deploy/.npmrc
    - sed -i -e "s/REGISTRY_PASSWORD-CI/$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD/g" ./deploy/.npmrc
    - cp ./deploy/package.json ./dist/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
    - cp ./deploy/.npmrc $HOME
    - cd ./dist/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
    - npm publish
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - ./dist
```

```
package_develop_gitlab:
  <<: *version_snapshot
  <<: *package_gitlab
  <<: *develop
```